# Why does the Cygwin chere package take up so much space?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-registry, cygwin

The `chere` package is currently [the easiest and most common method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder) to create a context menu item that opens a Cygwin terminal at a specific directory. When installing the package using the Cygwin installer, its size displays as 14KB:

[image]

However, after running the command needed to properly initiate and install the package:

```
chere -i -t mintty -s bash
```

...the package shows in IOBit Uninstaller as being 700MB, currently the largest program on my system:

[image]

That makes it bigger than all other programs on my PC, including fully-fledged software suites like Microsoft Office Professional and Firefox.

All the program seems to do is install 7 or so registry keys, each one containing minor variations on the following command:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe "%V"
```

Therefore, this isn't just a small discrepancy in size compared to the package's function - it's such a huge discrepancy in size that it must either be a severe bug or something malicious.

This issue isn't unique to Windows 10, as I recall Windows 7 actually reported an installed size of more than 1GB for the same package.

To rule out a bug with IOBit Uninstaller itself, I also ran Revo Uninstaller, which reports the same 770MB size:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not enumerating the total size of the cygwin directory under that one application? If you check the size of `C:\cygwin64`, is it around 770 MB?

Comment: @squircle No, my Cygwin folder is close to 3GB.

Comment: Is any subtree of the cygwin folder 770 MB? Specifically, folders at the level or below the `chere` executable (probably `\bin`). I'm almost certain that the applications you're using are miscalculating based on other unrelated files "near" the executable.

Comment: @squircle Good shout. It's the exact size of the `/bin` folder, confirmed by moving files out of it then re-checking the size in IOBit. It's beyond me why it does this instead of just reporting the size of its own executables as the Cwygin installer does, though.

Comment: In fairness, it's probably a good strategy for *most* Windows applications, because most program files are going to be inside (or below) the directory where the main executable is. Given how radically different the POSIX file structure is, it doesn't surprise me that it's counting all the other executables as collateral as well.

Comment: Good example of how you can't rule out a "bug" in one piece of software by trying only one other piece of software, though I'm going to be charitable and suggest that these are simple limitations (rather than "bugs" per se) owing to the way these POSIXy projects are laid out. No third-party "uninstaller" can get it 100% right.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings To be fair, Windows' own installer simply doesn't report size information for at least half of all programs, so I'd argue the third-party programs come closer to 100% than Windows itself does.

Comment: @Hashim Indeed, it's probably a decent heuristic, particularly for programs that follow Windows conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably (and now confirmed in the comments to be) the size of a sub-folder of the `C:\cygwin64` directory. Probably the location of the actual `chere` executable (so `C:\cygwin64\bin`).